# How to properly install the "Microsoft Speech" SDK

Tags: c#, sdk, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I want to use "Microsoft.Speech.Recognizion" for one of my C# projects so I had to download and install the SDK.

As [this documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362873(v=office.14).aspx) told me I downloaded the [Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225) and the [SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226) v11, installed it and then restarted my PC.

After windows had restarted it told me it had successfully installed the "updates", however there is no "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Speech" nor can I do anything in Visual Studio to get it running..

Did I make a mistake or is something buggy?

Comment: did you find the dll?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on Windows 10 at the moment myself, but have you tried the following options?

- Right click on the project > Add > Reference > *fileX*
- Check via Nugget Packages to see if you can download it

Comment: Good point, I just checked it and unfortunately I can't seem to find anything there...